# Wrong if comparison result in swift

Tags: swift

Consider the code below:

```
    var finalValue:Double!

    let aValue:Double = 1.6
    let bValue:Double = 64.0

    finalValue = bValue / (aValue*aValue)

    if finalValue == 25.0 {
        print("value \(finalValue) is equal to 25")
    } else {
        print("value \(finalValue) is not equal to 25")
    }
```

I expect the result is "value 25.0 is equal to 25"
But Xcode prints "value 25.0 is not equal to 25" which is wrong!!!!!

How can I solve the problem?

I'm using Xcode Version 7.0.1 (7A1001)

Comment: Welcome to floating point arithmetic. Suggest you do some reading about that topic.

Comment: Thanks. Finally I use this workaround: `let finalValueString: String = String(format: "%.1f", finalValue)
    ||||    finalValue = Double(finalValueString)`